# What is the proper name for the Myanmar temple in Myanmar’s largest city, Yangon?

Tags: temples, pilgrimage

I am looking for the proper/correct spelling of the Buddhist Temple structure in Yangon, Myanmar.  I have seen two names and I think they are both referencing the same place.
The names are:

Shwedagon Paya and Shwezigon Pagoda

(I believe Paya and Pagoda can also be switched in the above two names)

Are these name referring to the same Buddhist temple complex?

I plan on visiting this site next year.

Thank you.
Namaste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [official website here](http://www.shwedagonpagoda.com.mm/about-shwedagon-pagoda) calls it the "Shwedagon Pagoda".

Also, please see the [Visitors' Information](http://www.shwedagonpagoda.com.mm/visitors-information).

> No visit to the Union of Myanmar is complete without a visit to the
> 2,500 years old Shwedagon Pagoda, which enshrines strands of Buddha's
> hair and other holy relics. Located west of the Royal Lake on 114
> -acre Singuttara Hill in Yangon, Shwedagon Pagoda is the most sacred and impressive Buddhist site for the people of the Union of Myanmar.
> From a humble beginning of 8.2 meters, the Shwedagon Pagoda today
> stands close to 110 meters. Shwedagon Pagoda is covered with hundreds
> of gold plates and the top of the stupa is encrusted with 4531
> diamonds; the largest of which is a 72 carat diamond. It is clearly
> one of the wonders of the religious world. Shwedagon Pagoda is a
> repository of the best in Myanmar heritage - architecture, sculpture
> and arts. The Shwedagon Pagoda consists hundreds colorful temples,
> stupas, and statues that reflects the architectural era spanning
> almost a 2,500 years.

Comment: Are Shwezigon and Paya just another way of spelling the same location?  I ask because some travel guides use that spelling as well.

Comment: @tale852150 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shwezigon_Pagoda and Google Maps says that exists but is somewhere else i.e. Nyaung-U near the centre of the country, whereas https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shwedagon_Pagoda is in Yangon which is near the south coast.

Answer (score 3):

Shwedagon Pagoda is in Yangon and Shwezigon Pagoda is located at Bagan city.  Bagan city is also major tourist attraction place with the ancient city of Bagan where you can see ancient Buddhist religious building literally in every direction.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Burmese Wikipedia page, it gives the name...

ရွှေတိဂုံစေတီတော်
*shwaytigonehcaytetaw*

That transliteration of the Burmese script into Latin script is from Google Translate. The English-language Wikipedia page that the user "ruben2020" linked to earlier also substantiates "ရွှေတိဂုံစေတီတော်" as the "official name." It is uncited, so it is difficult to know if this information is correct. Wikipedia transcribes the Burmese into IPA like this...

"ʃwèdəɡòʊɰ̃ zèdìdɔ̀"

...but you'll need to look at the corresponding article on [Burmese IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/Burmese).

The "zèdì" in the above transcription looks like it is this same word [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%80%85%E1%80%B1%E1%80%90%E1%80%AE#Burmese) from Burmese Wiktionary. The other word Wiktionary lists for "stūpa/caitya" is "ဘုရား," or "pʰəjá." None of the earlier resources use that term, so it seems unlikely that that would be its "proper" name. Sorry I can't be more conclusive. Is there a Burmese language StackExchange? You could also try there too if such a thing exists.